# Static struct in C++

Tags: c++, static, struct, constants

I want to define an structure, where some math constants would be stored.
Here what I've got now:

```
struct consts {
    //salt density kg/m3
   static const double gamma;
};

const double consts::gamma = 2350;
```

It works fine, but there would be more than 10 floating point constants, so I doesn't want to wrote 'static const' before each of them. And define something like that:

```
static const struct consts {
    //salt density kg/m3
   double gamma;
};

const double consts::gamma = 2350;
```

It look fine, but I got these errors:
1. member function redeclaration not allowed
2. a nonstatic data member may not be defined outside its class

I wondering if there any C++ way to do it?

Comment: 10 is not many at all.  Just copy-paste the `static const double` portion.

Comment: I'm convinced that copy-paste in code is a biggest evil :)

Comment: Copy-paste of __logic__ is a big evil. Copy-paste of static const double... not so much. If you need 10 consts, you need to declare them.

Comment: copy-pasting functions or chunks of code you don't understand is patently evil.  But if all you have to do is type `static const double` 10 times and you're so lazy that you just can't do it, why not copy-paste?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use a namespace rather than trying to make a struct into a namespace.

```
namespace consts{
    const double gamma = 2350;
}
```

The method of accessing the data also has exactly the same synatx. So for example:

```
double delta = 3 * consts::gamma;
```

Comment: Sorry, I stamped over your change :(

Comment: @David No problem, thanks for the edit. I almost missed the fact that I had forgotten to put a type there.

Comment: Thank you! New to C++ and thanks for the lead on namespaces

Answer (score 11):

It sounds like you really just want a namespace:

```
namespace consts { 
    const double gamma = 2350.0;
    // ...
}
```

Except I'd try to come up with a better name than `consts` for it.