# Right location for class enum

Tags: c++, class, enums

I think this is more a stylistic question, but I have a class with an enum for statistic distribution type (that is only used in this class):

```
Entity {
public:
  enum DistributionType {NORM, UNIFORM_INT, UNIFORM_SPECIFIED, BINOMIAL };
  distributionType ds;
...
}
```

I want to make a DistributionType value as a parameter for my constructor:

```
Entity salesVolume = new Entity(Entity::DistributionType.NORM);
```

but this doesn't work (I guess it expects DistributionType when it's being passed an int value?)

**What is the right way to call a constructor with an enum value that is part of that same class?** I could do it by typecasting to int, but this doesn't seem very tight. I could also exclude the enum from the class and define it separately (which I've seen) - is that a more common way to do it?

Thanks guys

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639873/c-call-base-constructor-with-enum & please remember to up-vote if it helps.

Comment: Thanks Jay - checked that question, but it was bit beyond my C++ skills!

Comment: I avoid putting type definitions like this into classes. For me they are things on their own. Binding them to a class leads to code duplication or plain unreadable code if this exact type (logicaly) is needed in another class/place. Lets consider a "day of the week" enum. You probably want to avoid having several day of the week enums living in different classes. If you bind this enum to a class at first use and it gets used as parameter in 500 places and you then realize that you need it also in a second class you have a lot of refactoring to do to bring your codebase back to a logical state.

Comment: And it is unflexible because you can't move the enum to another header. Clients will always have to include the full entity header file into their header if the want to use the enum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With enums, there is no "namespace", so you need this:

```
Entity* salesVolume = new Entity(Entity::NORM);
```

C++11 provides "enum classes" or ["strongly typed enums"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Strongly_typed_enumerations) to solve this weirdness. It also allows you to use the enum name as a "scope" for traditional enums, so you could do this too:

```
Entity* salesVolume = new Entity(Entity::DistributionType::NORM); // C++11 only
```

Comment: Thanks Juan and Jay. Without strongly type enums in current C++, sort of defeats the purpose of including the enum in the class!

Comment: Well, at least it is in the class namespace, and not hanging out in the global one...

Comment: You could also make it static no? See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/127233/Typesafe-C-enum-with-ToString-and-FromString or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023643/static-struct-in-c

Comment: @jay that is a possibility, but then you can't use it as a "type" in an function parameter list, and you can *still* compare statics under different namespaces. The strongly typed enums are safer in this respect.

Comment: You could also create an enum outside with the same name and then inherit it in the class? Could you also not utilize a typedef here? see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16150/Inheriting-a-C-enum-type

Comment: Just curious what did you end up going with?

Comment: @Jay I'm not sure I follow the question. But I'm lucky to be able to use C++11 most of the time.

Comment: @juanchopanza, I was talking to the Pete :P that's my bad

Comment: @jay then you can comment under his question and he'll get it.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to it either as `Entity::NORM` or, more explicitly (in C++11), `Entity::DistributionType::Norm`.

However, on a stylistic note, this isn't Java. The code you showed will be slower and likely leak memory than just using the natural way of coding in C++, using automatic variables (variables created "on the stack"). Your code also won't compile because `new` gives you a pointer to the object. However, Instead of

```
Entity * salesVolume = new Entity(Entity::NORM);
```

Prefer

```
Entity salesVolume(Entity::NORM);
```

Comment: Actually, you can't necessarily do this. Maybe your compiler allows it, but it shouldn't be allowed in C++98, C++03. I *think* C++11 allows it though.

Comment: I just checked, your first statement is valid in C++11, but not C++03/C++98.

Comment: Oh, I guess I've been in C++11 land for too long. Editing.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please what error are you getting, since this code should work, Only problems are that :

1. you have defined ds as distributionType , while it should be DistributionType (capital "D").
2. Entity salesVolume = new Entity(Entity::DistributionType.NORM);  should be replaced with

Entity *salesVolume = new Entity(Entity::Entity.NORM);

Please Note the "*" before sa;esVolume. ie you have to declare it as pointer.

Comment: Even with the stackoverflow typos corrected, your code doesn't work with gcc ("error: expected primary-expression before '.' token"). I had to use the Answer example, but using the actual variable instance ie.  Entity* salesVolume = new Entity(salesVolume->NORM);

Comment: So the compiler thinks the instance version is different that the latter with an enum type? Interesting...